# Images in popup load well locally but not on web servers

Tags: jquery, image, magnific-popup

Hi my website has some problem loading images in magnific pop.
They loaded pretty well when I tested on local machine, but upon publishing, some popup does not load the images. Most of the images went through though.

A good example is the "3D modeling experience" button, none of the pictures shown, but other button works fine. Thanks for help!

the web site is [website](http://www.yiranthedesign.com/)

Comment: Your server answers with a 404 not found, so either you wrote the path to those images wrong, or did not upload them to your server …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images that cannot be shown are giving a 404 resource error. You need to change the file permissions  on the images so that everyone can read them. If you are using a Mac, cmd + I on an image and change the permissions, and reload it so that [this](http://www.yiranthedesign.com/portfolio/3d-modeling/3dmodeling2.jpeg) shows up.

On a side note, you spelled "Design" incorrectly :)

Comment: I just checked the bad images actually has the same permission as other pictures.. thank for correcting the typo though :)

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? For some reason the webpage can't find them. Maybe you named them .jpeg when they are another type of file? Did you host them the same way?

Comment: I figure out it's the caps problem, got some folders with "D" in the name but I referenced them as "d", for some reason it works on my local machine though and Brackets actually accept it.